# Applications crawl whenever they are on my third monitor

Tags: video, cpu, performance

I have a third monitor that whenever I interact with any apps on it, everything crawls. The mouse moves slowly, apps redraw slowly, etc. It's driving me nuts as you can imagine.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit using 1 GTX460 for 2x Samsung monitors and 1x 9800 for this problematic third Dell monitor.

It used to be that the only app that did this was Windows Live Messenger whenever someone shared an image/doc/video. However after updating Thunderbird it also experiences the same issue.

Any ideas what could be causing this, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is the slow monitor the one on the 9800? do you have good drivers for that card? are you using Windows or Linux, and if Linux, are you using the nVidia driver or Nouveau?

Comment: What's your total desktop resolution?  Does it work OK if all cards are set to a lower resolution (therefore lowering your total desktop res.)?

Comment: Yes the "slow" issue was happening on the monitor connected to the 9800. The issue occurs with the older drivers as well as the latest drivers. And yes, as stated this is under Windows 7 64bit.

As for the resolution, the 2x 24" run at 1920 x 1200 and the 20" runs at 1680 x 1050. This is the native resolution for each monitor.

Comment: If the other adapter *does* have drivers installed, then make sure that it has hardware acceleration enabled.